# Electric potential inside a shell

Tags: electrostatics, potential, field-theory

Inside a shell, electric field is zero. Then does it have a constant electric potential inside the shell?

If $V=\dfrac Ed$, then since field is zero, potential should also have been zero. Please explain!

Comment: That is kind of the point - the potential everywhere on the sphere is the same (or else charge would move in response). However, there is no requirement that the sphere as a whole can not be at some potential relative to something else.

Comment: "*if v=E/d...*": no, $E=\partial V/\partial d$, which means that $V$ can be nonzero  even if $E=0$...

Comment: where do you get v = E/d?  This not correct in general

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform dropped a minus sign

Answer (score 3):

First of all, electrostatic field is conservative in nature. So this force can be written as the gradient of a scalar potential V

$E=-∇V$

The d in your equation is not right. The gradient indicates the rate of change of V with respect to the three coordinates along the three directions. Since the electric field is zero, we can write

$∇V=0$

which means the potential has no change along the three axes. That's why we say the potential is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

"*Potential at a point is sort of energy you used to move a point particle.*"It is work done to move a unit positive charge in a field.

Consider a shell with radius r and charge q.

Potential at infinity is taken as 0 by convention.

When you move a charge from infinity to surface of shell , you did work $W = \frac{kq}{r}$ in present of electric field **E**.

Now, you move charge from Surface to center, you have to do no work since there is no field.

Total work you did $= W = \frac{kq}{r}$ 
to move the charge from infinity to center.

Remember, Potential is work done to move a unit positive charge in a field.

Thus, the potential at center is work done to move unit charge from infinity to center which is $\frac{kq}{r}$ .

**Bonus:** You may consider potential at center =0. No, physicist will deny it. But, it will mean you are creating your own references. 
In this case both electric field and potential at center would become exactly 0.
But, potential at infinity becomes -kq/r.